# Can I use java mail sender in production?

Tags: smtp, jakarta-mail

In development, I am using java mail sender to send mail notification.

But one issue till I found is, google algorithms use suspicious algorithm to check.
And in java mail sender I saw it some time. Till that time, you can't send email. Until you go to that machine from where you are calling and in-browser login with that credential and review activity in any system.

Is there any free version?

Best paid version I can think of Amazon AWS own SMTP  server.

Comment: In google , you can ON l Allow less secure apps.

Comment: yeah yeah, still it came at least for first time. I am in doubt if it may come again.